# Проблема с таймером, который через интервал времени вызывает нестатический метод

Tags: windows, c++11

Что уже есть:

```
#include <functional>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <agents.h>
#include <ppltasks.h>

    template <class T>
    void call_after(T& callback, unsigned int timeInMs)
    {
        concurrency::task_completion_event<void> tce;
        auto call = new concurrency::call<int>(
            [callback, tce](int)
        {
            callback();
            tce.set();
        });

        auto timer = new concurrency::timer<int>(timeInMs, 0, call, false);
        concurrency::task<void> event_set(tce);
        event_set.then([timer, call]()
        {
            delete call;
            delete timer;
        });

        timer->start();
    }
```

Что не получается:

```
std::function<void()> callback = this->Disconnect; // тут ошибка, C3867 (в вызове функции отсутствует список аргументов)
call_after(callback, 5000);
```

Метод `this->Disconnect()` - нестатический метод класса, который имеет возвращяемый тип `void` и не принимает никаких аргументов.

Вопрос: как решить данную проблему? Как по таймеру, через интервал времени вызвать метод, который является нестатическим членом класса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какие-то такие варианты:

```
std::function<void()> callback1 = std::bind(&Foo::Disconnect, this);
std::function<void()> callback2 = [this](){this->Disconnect();};
```

Написав `this->Disconnect`, вы не берёте объект типа `std::function`, а вызываете функцию без аргументов.

Comment: Спасибо, первый вариант с bind подошел, второй вариант нерабочий, компилятор ругается на ошибку синтаксиса.

Comment: Была опечатка же. Перепутал порядок пустых скобок. Будьте внимательнее.